# How the best and fast way to hide option not needed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML select with several option and i want to hide and show back when needed, as example here my HTML :

```
<select>
<option value="0">A</option>
<option value="1">B</option>
<option value="2">C</option>
<option value="3">D</option>
<option value="4">E</option>
<option value="5">F</option>
<option value="6">G</option>
<option value="7">H</option>
</select>
```

Now i just want to show option E and hide other option. But in other case maybe i want to show all. I know in JavaScript we can hide one option by their value. But i want to know are they best way to hide and show it according performance too (with **Javascript**)?

Thank you.

Comment: None of these answers are mentioning performance at all; did anyone read the question? OP says already knows *how* to do it with JS..

Comment: @Adam Anyone taking the performance seriously would know that there is no discernible difference for so few elements

Comment: Please tell us how (on what conditions) you are going to determine which to show and which not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have hidden attribute for that

```js
var myselectoptions=document.getElementById("myselect").options;

function hideoptions(optionObject,optiontohide){
  for (index = 0; index < optiontohide.length; ++index) {
    optionObject[optiontohide[index]].setAttribute('hidden','true');
  }
}

function showoptions(optionObject,optiontoshow){
  for (index = 0; index < optiontoshow.length; ++index) {
    optionObject[optiontoshow[index]].removeAttribute("hidden");
  }
}

hideoptions(myselectoptions, [6,7,8]);      // hide F,G,H
showoptions(myselectoptions, [8]);         // show H
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="0" >Select</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
  <option value="4">D</option>
  <option value="5">E</option>
  <option value="6">F</option>
  <option value="7">G</option>
  <option value="8">H</option>
</select>
```

> For support on IE < 11 add this line to css : **[hidden] { display: none; }**

Jquery can also be used but I think plain Javascript code would be faster as Jquery performs a lot of checks on a function.

Comment: How to do that with Javascript ?

Comment: @Michael Does it helps? This is just an example. Please select options in a formal approach because this code will give you all the options on the page.

Comment: also 'hidden' attribute is not supported on IE<11. For supporting this on IE<11 add this line to css : **[hidden] { display: none; }**

Comment: op[4] means option E right? if i want to hide A i just need to change the code to op[0] ?

Comment: @Michael right, it gives you an array of option in the order in which they appear in your Html code. Just give an id to this 'select' option and select option using that id to get only these options in your array

Comment: @Michael Revised my answer. Now it looks better!

Comment: @Michael change your code to this as this doesn't work for the **option '0'**. Better provide a default option there

Comment: This work but i think need more idea when i want to switch what hide and what show . I mean if i only show 1 option and then i want to switch to show all and then we have a lot of options. Will it decrease the performance ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way it's work fine :

```js
 $('#btnE').click(function () {
        $("#select option").show();
        $("#select option[value!=4]").hide();
    });

    $('#btnB').click(function () {
        $("#select option").show();
        $("#select option[value!=1]").hide();
    });

    $('#btnAll').click(function () {
        $("#select option").show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="0">A</option>
    <option value="1">B</option>
    <option value="2">C</option>
    <option value="3">D</option>
    <option value="4">E</option>
    <option value="5">F</option>
    <option value="6">G</option>
    <option value="7">H</option>
</select>
<br /><br />

<input type="button" value="Show Only E" id="btnE" />
<input type="button" value="Show Only B" id="btnB" />
<input type="button" value="Show All" id="btnAll" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide using `.hide()` function

```js
jQuery('select').children('option[value="4"]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
  <option value="3">D</option>
  <option value="4">E</option>
  <option value="5">F</option>
  <option value="6">G</option>
  <option value="7">H</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for hiding only single option from the select
$('select').children('option[value="1"]').hide();

//for showing only one option from the select
$('select').children('option').hide(); 

$('select').children('option[value="1"]').show();
```

Be more specific to select element as this will work on all select list and can cause errors so use $("select:class") etc...